# Liferay alloy-ui validator

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui

I want to change validator alloy-ui messages like  "this field is required"  by using a hook or other methods, but I cant find those messages location??

Answer (score 1):

You can override /html/js/liferay/form.js in some hook and change line
 required: Liferay.Language.get('this-field-is-required')
And provide your custom language key for it.

If you want to change this language label for whole portal, then in some hook override Language properties and modify label for key this-field-is-required

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var formValidator = new A.FormValidator({
                        boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace/>yourForm',
                        rules: {
                            <portlet:namespace/>yourInput: {
                                required: true,
                                baseChars: true
                            }
                        },
                        fieldStrings: {
                            <portlet:namespace/>yourInput: {
                                required: 'Your custom required message'
                            }
                        },
                        showAllMessages: true
                    });
```

Then if you want to test if your form is valid just use:

```
if (formValidator.hasErrors()) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                       //your code
                        }
```

You can replace **required: 'Your custom required message'** by **Liferay.Language.get('your-required-custom-message')**